# How to get CLOB output from Oracle Stored Procedure using ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, odp.net, clob

I want to call a stored procedure in Oracle which has a CLOB as an output parameter. I'm using following code to call, but getting error -

```
var sql = @"DECLARE
                       l_clob CLOB;
                       l_inv_type nm_inv_types.nit_inv_type%TYPE := 'SULA';
                    BEGIN
                       xmrwa_inv_type_xml.get_inv_type_xml(pi_nit_inv_type => l_inv_type
                                                          ,po_xml          => l_clob
                                                          );   
                      RETURNING l_clob INTO :key;
                    END;
                    ";

        var connString = string.Format(connectionString, OracleDBUser, OracleDBPassword);
        using (var conn = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connString))
        using (var command = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();


            // make the :key parameter an output param
            var p2 = command.Parameters.Add(":key", null);
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;

            var v = command.ExecuteReader();


        }
```

Error Detais - ORA-06550: line 8, column 39:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "L_CLOB" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;

Could somebody please help me with the resolution?

Comment: That sql is not a call to a stored procedure. That's the definition _of_ a stored procedure. You should just call `xmrwa_inv_type_xml.get_inv_type_xml(...)` in your `command`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

> ;

after end closure